# Stereo camera baseline not needed for calibration?

Tags: computer-vision, calibration, stereo-vision

I am doing stereo camera calibration as described in [this blog post](http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html). I wonder I do not need to input camera baseline for the calibration. The fact probably goes back to some very basic mathematics of triangulation. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

The baseline is an output parameter of the calibration. What the calibration needs to know is the size of your calibration object. How it works is to find the transformation between the two views, and reduce the overall error for multiple views. The transformation is both the rotation and the translation. The translation in this case is the baseline.